# Is this password encryption safe enough?

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, openssl, md5

I was thinking of doing a simple password upgrade to a system that at the moment has something like this:

```
md5(md5($pass) . $user);
```

The password will pass through a JavaScript hashing algorithm before being sent and this always makes a three characters password about 20+ characters.

I thought using the ends of the hashed password as KEY and IV to encrypt the rest should should suffice.

```
$pass = '20_plus_characters_long';
$hash = openssl_encrypt(substr($pass, 5, -5), 'aes-128-cbc', substr($pass, 0, 5), false, md5(substr($pass, -5), true));
```

Am I correct?

Comment: Why are you hashing the password in javascript rather than using SSL; and why then encrypt the `hash` in PHP?

Comment: I would vote against that (both ideas). Take a look at https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several weaknesses in your scheme. Actually you encrypt the password and throw away the key.

1. You take only 5 (base64 encoded) characters as the key, so an
   attacker needs about 1 Giga tries to crack the hash in the database
   (for comparison, everybody can crack 8 Giga MD5 hashes per second).
   This cracked database-hash can then be brute forced with the
   `md5(md5($pass) . $user)` scheme, which is also ways too fast.
2. Since you do not add a random salt in the MD5 part, an attacker
   could prepare rainbow-tables for specific accounts like user
   "admin", then the only protection is the weak encryption part.

Actually there is no advantage over the standard way with the [password_hash()](http://php.net/password_hash) function. This function will produce a BCrypt hash, and the cost factor determines the needed time for calculation to thwart brute-force attacks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this password encryption safe enough?

Probably not, but it depends on your threat model.

Two users with the same password will have the same entry in the password database. That's a loss in PRP-security (pseudo-random permutation). That is, an attacker will be able to distinguish a random answer from a real answer.

---

> `md5(md5($pass) . $user);`

You should probably look at Openwall's [Portable PHP password hashing framework (phpass)](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) and John Steven's [Secure Password Storage](http://docs.google.com/document/d/1R6c9NW6wtoEoT3CS4UVmthw1a6Ex6TGSBaEqDay5U7g). Steven even takes you through the threat model and explains why you do things.

Comment: Since the username is probably unique, two equal passwords will result in different hashes. But yes, it is not a good scheme.